# How to use keyboard keys combination in angular hostlistener

Tags: angular, angular7, keyboard-shortcuts

When the user pressing keys ALT+M then ALT+E, I want show mat dialog modal.

Comment: Please consider updating you question so more people can use this and the corresponding answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6):

According to your question to capture ALT+M and ALT+E

```
    @HostListener('window:keydown.Alt.m', ['$event']) 
    onKeyDownAltM(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(e);    
       console.log('ALT + M');
   }
   @HostListener('window:keydown.Alt.e', ['$event']) 
    onKeyDownAltE(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(e);    
       console.log('ALT + E');
   }
```

That's it you are good to go!
For Key Codes [Reference](https://keycode.info/)
Stack Blitz working example [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keycombination)